# Error creating foreign key on userid, followerid (check data types)

Tags: mysql

Hey I'm having issues setting foreign keys pointing from my followings table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `followings` (
  `id` int(26) NOT NULL,
  `userid` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `followerid` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

to my users table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(26) NOT NULL,
  `userid` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `handle` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `dateofbirth` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `phoneverified` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailverified` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authentic` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `datecreated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

    ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `handle` (`handle`);
```

I have checked the collation etc of the fields are the same yet i am still getting an error on phpmyadmin

```
Error creating foreign key on userid, followerid (check data types)
```

Any possible reasons for such error

This is the sql generated by phpmyadmin before the error

```
ALTER TABLE `followings` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`userid`, `followerid`) REFERENCES `users`(`userid`, `userid`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: Not sure that can work like that. I would make 2 separate foreign keys to each column and then add a unique key over both columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be making a multi-key foreign key. You need separate foreign keys for `userid` and `followerid`, since they refer to different rows in the `users` table.

```
ALTER TABLE followings ADD FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users (userid);
ALTER TABLE followings ADD FOREIGN KEY (followerid) REFERENCES users (userid);
```

Also, it's usually preferable to have the foreign key reference the primary key.